# How many pets can I keep in an aquarium?

Tags: aquarium, fish, freshwater

I recently got a 5.5 gallon fish tank and am curious about the quantity of animals I can have in the tank. I currently own six fish. I don't know their proper names, but I own one bottom feeder fish(the black ones that clean the tank) and five smaller fish that won't grow past two inches, as well as one snail.

I'm curious, would 2 frogs and/or a couple shrimp live comfortably inside a tank of this size? What are the limits when adding other types of animals to a fish tank?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close to the max number of fish as it is now so you should not add any more fish to your aquarium.

Here is a link to how many fish you can have http://www.howmanyfish.com/ and please read all of it.

Please remember the numbers given in the link is just an estimate so you need to have fewer fish in your tank as there is many variables like How good are the filter-The amount of decorations in your tank-Temparature in your tank-How often you do maitenance(changes water and clean your tank)-The amount of food you give the fish and lots more.

A larger aquarium takes less work to keep running than a small one so it is best to go for the largest aquarium you can.